# iphone: Parsing while the app is closed.

Tags: iphone, parsing

I am developing an iphone app that needs to parse data received from server. When the app is open the parsing is fine. However, I have to show the status change with a badge when the app is closed. I am not able to parse when the app is closed and hence the badge doesn't show-up. How to do parsing when the app is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you will be able to start a background progress for the parsing, but I don't think you will be able to update the application badge.

Have a look at the documentation on background code execution: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4

Comment: please provide new link,because in the current link page not found error is coming.

Comment: Or just wait until the site loads the correct URL:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this - [**Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** do it with background process.. Instead go for push-notification.